# Obtain all OAuthTokens from account

Tags: oauth, accesstoken

Iv'e came across [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_oauthtoken.htm) data object.

I am wondering how can I fetch all of the token which are related to my account (and all of my end users as-well).

I did not quite understand which and how to trigger an endpoint for that using REST.

Any help / example would be appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit: I may have not been clear enough:
I do not want to obtain the tokens themselves, I just want information on which connected apps are authorized to access my users data. Is there any way to do that? (Just looking for metadata)**

Comment: Accessing OAuth tokens for other people sounds like a security disaster waiting to happen. What exactly is it that you're trying to do with that data?

Comment: I am the admin. I want to see which OAuth tokens are correlated to my user to enforce security.

Comment: Asking for everyone's OAuth token is basically asking for a list of passwords... what type of security are you trying to enforce here?    Salesforce authenticates users, right... and then you generate permissions based upon users, profiles, etc....

Really more information is needed.  I could go on for an hour about OAuth connections (sadly..lol)

Comment: I just want to know which connected apps are authorized to access my users, thats it. Why is it so weird in your eyes?

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want a list of all the OAuth Tokens, it is like asking for a list of passwords.

See this post: [How to Get list of "Connected Apps OAuth Usage"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339920/how-to-get-list-of-connected-apps-oauth-usage)

The comment under the answer suggests everything except deleting a token returns a  value.

Your updated question can be answered if you review:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_manage.htm&type=5

Comment: I looked at this thread, I did not understand how to obtain such list.
As I wrote in my edit, I do not wish to obtain the tokens themselves, I just want to get the list of connected apps and see which apps are authorized to obtain information from my end users.
Could you please share an example of a GET request which results in such data?

Comment: Seriously, this answer was for your first question:  " how can I fetch all of the token which are related to my account "

Your second question, how do I find out all the connected apps that have access by which user is a different question.

Is this how you ask people for help usually?

Comment: Sorry for my English.

Comment: No worries.  Sorry for assuming English was your first language. Welcome to the StackExchange people are here to help!  Look at the article I added.  If you need additional information, let me know (with more detail if you can) and I will help!

Comment: Thanks. Once again - I am sorry for my English or any miss-understanding.
What I am trying to achieve is - obtaining all of my connected apps programmatically via some REST API or something similar. I just want to see which apps are authorized to have access to my users. Is this possible?

Comment: I spent about an hour looking.  I can't find anything other than the normal Setup page.  Maybe it would be helpful to understand why you need it more specifically... why do you need this info from a REST Endpoint?