# Programmatically obtain metadata about OAuth Connect Apps

Tags: rest-api, chatter, connected-apps

I want to programmatically obtain metadata about my OAuth connected apps.
What do I mean by that? For example - I have docu-sign connected to one of my users, I would like to retrieve this data somehow (maybe data about what docu-sign are authorized to obtain from my user). By any means I do not mean that I want to obtain the tokens themselves.

Ive encountered this thread:  [How to Get list of "Connected Apps OAuth Usage"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339920/how-to-get-list-of-connected-apps-oauth-usage)

But I did not quite understand how to grab that data in a RESTfull manner.

I have some experience with Chatter API - I am able to see which users are linked to my salesforce account. (Im an admin). Next step that I wish to achieve is to see which connected apps are authorized to obtain which data from my users.

Is this possible? If so I would be glad to see an example.  Thanks!

Comment: _maybe data about what docu-sign are authorized to obtain from my user_ - this is dictated by `scope` on the connected app. Metadata API helps with this https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/354257/retrieving-oauth-scopes-from-an-installed-connected-app . SOAP only.

Comment: Oh boy, there's no REST api support for this? @identigral

Comment: Not for this use case, no.